# Pen tool "snapping" to points

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Something I've noticed lately in the newer CC versions of Illustrator is the pen tool is "snapping" to other paths/objects when I get my tool near to it.

For reference, I have ALL snapping features off. My selection tolerance is down to 1px, I have rubber band turned off for the pen tool. It *shouldn't* be going anywhere other than where I have my pen tool hovering, yet it's still jumping around.

I'm specifically noticing it when I need to be zoomed out, because I'm going to be adding anchors over a large area. I thought maybe it was my Wacom tablet cause I've had so many issues with it since updating to 2017, but I'm starting to think this is just a really crappy version.

Comment: Yes it does that... Contact adobe. THe number of lemon features in all adobe CC versions is so staggering that most users have rolled back to cs 6. I mean breaking the zoom function was the real bonus in the new version.

Comment: Do you have Smart Guides enabled?

Comment: Just another thought, make sure you have "Align Art to Pixel Grid" button switched off in the Pen Tool options. This one often causes major headaches

Answer (score 2):

In Illustrator CC 2018:

Uncheck View > Smart Guides

Voila - no more jumping pen tool.

Answer (score 2):

I thought you might want to know that I found Illustrator has additional options within the "View" menu which fixed my problem.

Uncheck "Snap to Pixel" and "Snap to Point" within the View menu. I did the options above along with these, and now my Pen tool works as expected.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same issue and solved it. It was not the usual suspects (Snapping settings under View) but the settings under "Preferences > Selection & anchor display". Make sure "Snap to point" is off. This fixed it for me. No more intrusive snapping.

Answer (score -2):

You should uncheck snap to pixels

Comment: Hello Thomas. The questioner already said "I have ALL snapping features off." Also, we typically look for longer answers, that don't just say what box to tick or button to click, but also why that option would work and what the principles behind it are. Feel free to browse the site, leave more answers and maybe leave a question of your own.